# Get name of argument of function in lua

Tags: lua

When call a lua function like

PrintMe(MyVariableName)

I would like to be able to actually print "MyVariableName" and not it's value(well, for demo purposes).

Obviously I could just pass the string but that requires extra quotes and I also would like to print it's value.

e.g.,

```
MyVariable = 4
PrintVariable(MyVariable)
```

Would print "MyVariable is 4" or whatever

I do not want to have to duplicate the name and variable like

```
PrintVariable(MyVariable, "MyVariable")
```

as this is unnecessary duplication.

Can lua handle it?

What I'm doing now is passing the variable name in quotes and using loadstring to get the value but I would like to just pass the variable directly without the extra unnecessary quotes(which I thought debug.getlocal did but it ends up returning the value instead of the name).

---

Here is mock example

```
function printme1(var, val)
    print(var.." = "..val)
end

function printme2(v)
    local r
    loadstring("r = "..v)() -- equivalent to r = a but must be used since v is a string representing a and not the object a
    print(v.." = "..tostring(r))
end

function printme3(v)
    -- unknown
end

a = 3

printme1("a", a)
printme2("a")
printme3(a)
```

In this case all 3 should print the same thing. printme3 obviously is the most convenient.

Comment: You can do it without calling loadstring (see my example), but you can't do it without the quotes. Not robustly. There's just nothing in the API that would tell you what you need. You *could* look for a local in the caller's scope that has the value you passed it, but that would be unreliable. I'll show you how to write that anyway (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

You can't say `PrintVariable(MyVariable)`, because Lua gives you no way of determining which variable (if any; a constant could have been used) was used to pass an argument to your function. However, you *can* say `PrintVariable('MyVariable')` then used the debug API to look for a local variable in the caller's scope which has that name:

```
function PrintVariable(name)
  -- default to showing the global with that name, if any
  local value = _G[name]

  -- see if we can find a local in the caller's scope with that name
  for i=1,math.huge do
    local localname, localvalue = debug.getlocal(2,i,1)
    if not localname then
      break -- no more locals to check
    elseif localname == name then
      value = localvalue
    end
  end

  if value then
    print(string.format("%s = %s", name, tostring(value)))
  else
    print(string.format("No variable named '%s' found.", name))
  end
end
```

Now you can say:

```
PrintVariable('MyVariable')
```

While in this case will print "MyVariable = 4".

---

Not, if you *really* want to do this without the quotes, you could check the caller's locals for variables that have a supplied value, but that's occasionally going to give you the wrong variable name if there is more than one variable in the caller's scope with a given value. With that said, here's how you'd do that:

```
function PrintVariable(value)
  local name

  -- see if we can find a local in the caller's scope with the given value
  for i=1,math.huge do
    local localname, localvalue = debug.getlocal(2,i,1)
    if not localname then
      break
    elseif localvalue == value then
      name = localname
    end
  end

  -- if we couldn't find a local, check globals
  if not name then
    for globalname, globalvalue in pairs(_G) do
      if globalvalue == value then
        name = globalname
      end
    end
  end

  if name then
    print(string.format("%s = %s", name, tostring(value)))
  else
    print(string.format("No variable found for the value '%s'.", tostring(value)))
  end
end
```

Now you can say `PrintVariable(MyVariable)`, but if there happened to be another variable in the caller's scope with the value `4`, and it occurred before `MyVariable`, it's *that* variable name that will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news, my friend.  You can access function parameter names as they appear at the top of the function, but the data to access exactly what they were named in the calling function does not exist.  See the following:

```
function PrintVariable(VariableToPrint)
  --we can use debug.getinfo() to determine the name 'VariableToPrint'
  --we cannot determine the name 'MyVariable' without some really convoluted stuff (see comment by VBRonPaulFan on his own answer)
  print(VariableToPrint);
end

MyVariable = 4
PrintVariable(MyVariable)
```

To illustrate this, imagine if we had done:

```
x = 4
MyVariable = x
MyOtherVariable = x
x = nil

PrintVariable(MyVariable)
```

Now if you were Lua, what name would you attach in the metadata to the variable that ends up getting passed to the function?  Yes, you could walk up the stack with debug.getint() looking for the variable that was passed in, but you may find several references.
Also consider:

```
PrintVariable("StringLiteral")
```

What would you call that variable?  It has a value but no name.

Comment: The OP cannot recover the variable names he wants, however it is not true that "local variable names cease to exist". You can recover them all with `debug.getlocal`. However, they are recovered according to stack level and the order they were created. There's no way to recover the ones that were used to pass values to a function.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I want Nathan(or I don't understand you)... I've updated my post to include the code that I use but with the cavet I have to pass strings instead.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post to try to explain myself a little more clearly with formatted code examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can do stuff like this with the debug library... something like this does what you seem to be looking for:

```
function a_func(arg1, asdf)
    -- if this function doesn't use an argument... it shows up as (*temporary) in 
    -- calls to debug.getlocal() because they aren't used...
    if arg1 == "10" then end
    if asdf == 99 then end
    -- does stuff with arg1 and asdf?
end

-- just a function to dump variables in a user-readable format
function myUnpack(tbl)
    if type(tbl) ~= "table" then
        return ""
    end

    local ret = ""
    for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
        if tostring(v) ~= "" then
            ret = ret.. tostring(k).. "=".. tostring(v).. ", "
        end
    end
    return string.gsub(ret, ", $", "")
end

function hook()
    -- passing 2 to to debug.getinfo means 'give me info on the function that spawned 
    -- this call to this function'. level 1 is the C function that called the hook.
    local info = debug.getinfo(2)
    if info ~= nil and info.what == "Lua" then
        local i, variables = 1, {""}
        -- now run through all the local variables at this level of the lua stack
        while true do
            local name, value = debug.getlocal(2, i)
            if name == nil then
                break
            end
            -- this just skips unused variables
            if name ~= "(*temporary)" then
                variables[tostring(name)] = value
            end
            i = i + 1
        end
            -- this is what dumps info about a function thats been called
        print((info.name or "unknown").. "(".. myUnpack(variables).. ")")
    end
end

-- tell the debug library to call lua function 'hook 'every time a function call
-- is made...
debug.sethook(hook, "c")

-- call a function to try it out...
a_func("some string", 2012)
```

this results in the output:

```
a_func(asdf=2012, arg1=some string)
```

you can do fancier stuff to pretty this up, but this basically covers how to do what you're asking.

Comment: You misread the original post.  He is looking to determine the name of the variables in their scope outside the function (see his current work-around), not the name used by the function for its parameters.  In other words, he is not looking to determine "asdf" and "arg1", but "a" and "b" if the caller executed a_func(a, b).

Comment: ahh, gotcha. that might be possible if you attempt to walk up the stack to try to figure out what locals are in scope with matching values to what was passed to the called function. seems like an awful lot of work for a demo, though...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this form:

```
local parms = { "MyVariable" }

local function PrintVariable(vars)
   print(parms[1]..": "..vars[1])
end

local MyVariable = "bar"

PrintVariable{MyVariable}
```

Which gives:

```
MyVariable: bar
```

It isn't generic, but it is simple. You avoid the debug library and loadstring by doing it this way. If your editor is any good, you could write a macro to do it.

Comment: You could also do the same thing with a list fx(param, name, param, name) then just use select() to get the name

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is add this facility your self.
The Lua C API and source is pretty simple and extendable.

I/we don't know the context of your project/work but if you ARE making/embedding your own Lua build you could extend the `debug` library with something to do this.

Lua passes it's values by reference, but unknown offhand if these contain a string name in them and if so if easily accessible.

In your example the value declaration is the same as:

```
_G["MyVariable"] = 4
```

Since it's global. If it were declared `local` then like others stated here you can enumerate those via `debug.getlocal()`. But again in the C context of the actual reference context it might not matter.

Implement a `debug.getargumentinfo(...)` that extends the argument table with name key, value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old topic and I apologize for bringing it back to life.

In my experience with lua, the closest I know to what the OP asked for is something like this:

```lua
PrintVariable = {}
setmetatable(PrintVariable, {__index = function (self, k, v) return string.format('%s = %s', k, _G[k]) end})

VAR = 0
VAR2 = "Hello World"

print(PrintVariable.VAR, PrintVariable.VAR2)
-- Result: VAR = 0  VAR2 = Hello World
```

I do not give more explanation, because the code is quite readable, however:
What happens here is simple, you only set a metatable to the `PrintVariable` variable and add the `__index` metamethod that is called when the table is forced to search for a value in its index, thanks to this functionality you can achieve what you see in the example.

Reference: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

I hope that future and new visitors will find this helpful.